# Can't boot Ubuntu 20.xx images work from Windows 10 on SD Card Libre Computer ROC-RK3328-CC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, disk-image

I am able to image an SD Card using the images on firefly's site for Ubuntu 18.06 LTS and it boots fine.

However, when I get the images for Ubuntu 20.xx server or desktop they do not appear to work.

The red and green lights shine brightly while there is no HDMI output, maybe there is UART output, but I can't see it because the baud rate is too high.  I do not have an eMMC module.

Please include the following items in your post or else it is very hard for someone to help you on a particular issue.

1. What image are you using?

   - ubuntu-22.04.1-preinstalled-desktop-arm64+roc-rk3328-cc.img.xz
   - ubuntu-22.04.1-preinstalled-server-arm64+roc-rk3328-cc.img.xz
   - ubuntu-22.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+roc-rk3328-cc.img.xz
2. Where are you getting your image?

   - https://computer-libre-distro.us-east-1.linodeobjects.com//ci/ubuntu/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-preinstalled-desktop-arm64+roc-rk3328-cc.img.xz
   - https://computer-libre-distro.us-east-1.linodeobjects.com//ci/ubuntu/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-preinstalled-server-arm64+roc-rk3328-cc.img.xz
   - https://computer-libre-distro.us-east-1.linodeobjects.com//ci/ubuntu/22.10/ubuntu-22.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+roc-rk3328-cc.img.xz
3. Are you flashing to a MicroSD card or eMMC module?

   MicroSD
4. If you are not getting video, what tool are you using to flash the image?
   I have tried...

   - balenaEtcher
   - SD Card Installer (also Etcher apparently)
   - Win32DiskImager